# NavigationManager.Uri does not update at all unless page is refreshed. How to get real current URI in Blazor Server?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a link in a side menu like this (Blazor Server):

```
<NotAuthorized>
  <li class="nav-item px-3">
    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="@($"LoginIDP?redirectUri=
    {NavigationManager.Uri}")">
       Login
    </NavLink>
  </li>
</NotAuthorized>
```

The idea is simple: I want to keep the `redirectUri={NavigationManager.Uri}` part updated with the current Uri the user is on at all times, so no matter on which page/component the user clicks the login link, the correct `redirectUri` is always passed to the login page.

But in reality, as the user clicks various other `<NavLink>` on the page, the URI in the browser's address bar does change, so does the page content, but `NavigationManager.Uri` remains the same unless I refresh the page.

Is this by design? How do I obtain the real current Uri without changing every link to some event call that forces updates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you click on a button, the page changes only the content, but the component where you render `NavigationManager.Uri` isn't rerendered, so you probably need to rerender the component in some way to do that.

On way you can do that is to subscribe to the [NavigationManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.navigationmanager)'s [LocationChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.navigationmanager.locationchanged) event and call `StateHasChanged` to rerender the component.

You can take a look at [this example from the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing#uri-and-navigation-state-helpers) and modify it a little bit.

```
@implements IDisposable
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

@* Your component *@
<NotAuthorized>
  <li class="nav-item px-3">
    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="@($"LoginIDP?redirectUri=
    {NavigationManager.Uri}")">
       Login
    </NavLink>
  </li>
</NotAuthorized>

@code {
    
    private void HandleLocationChanged(object sender, LocationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // rerender component
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        // add to the NavigationManager event
        NavigationManager.LocationChanged += HandleLocationChanged;

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // remove from the NavigationManager event
        NavigationManager.LocationChanged -= HandleLocationChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The child component not re-rendering is indeed the issue. So all I had to do was to hook into the ```NavigationManager.LocationChanged``` event and call ```StateHasChanged```, which will re-render the parent component (a NavMenu in my case) as well as the children. Your code as is still needs ```StateHasChanged``` to work. The ```currentLocation``` wasn't necessary, as ```StateHasChanged``` will re-render ```NavigationManager.Uri```.

Comment: @thankyoussd if that solved your problem, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted and give an upvotr, thanks!